# Levenshtein distance bias

Tags: code-golf, string, edit-distance

Write a program in a language with name `A` that, given a string `S`, outputs the name of a different programming language `B`. The length of `B` must be equal to the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) (abbr. "LD") between `A` and `S`. To be considered a programming language, `B` must have an esolangs page or a Wikipedia page.

### Example:

```
(Suppose the program is coded in Python)
Input: Jython
Output: R
Input: Pyt4oq
Output: Go
Input: Rs7hon
Output: C++
```

The LD between `Python` and `Jython` is one, so the output `R`

You only need to cover up to an LD of up to `12`. You can assume that an LD of `0` will never occur.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program in bytes wins.

(This is my first challenge! Feedback is appreciated)

---

## Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=58974,OVERRIDE_USER=20260;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Why `12`? Are there not languages with larger names?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ It just seemed liek a reasonabl upperbnd.

Comment: @ThomasKwa I believe `R` is a programming language... it could have easily been `C`, `D`, etc.

Comment: so, you mean a name with a *length* equal to the Levenshtein distance? What counts as a programming language? Must it have an esolangs/Wikipedia page?

Comment: @ThomasKwa Yes (to the first). Either an esolang or wikipedia page will suffice

Comment: The LD of "Patton" and "Python" is 2, not 3.

Comment: This is a question that implicitly denies the validity of MetaCodeGolf, as it it becomes circular!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## O, 107 bytes

Using the tip from @histocrat to make the distance calculation simpler.  Also used languages with The same starting letter to remove a few characters

```
"pyrodecimal""hakespeare""tackstack""nowflake""nowball""nowman""onata""ADOL""taq""oT""R"""ie\'O<-1-{;}d'Soo
```

[Try it here](http://o-lang.herokuapp.com/link/code=%22pyrodecimal%22%22hakespeare%22%22tackstack%22%22nowflake%22%22nowball%22%22nowman%22%22onata%22%22ADOL%22%22taq%22%22oT%22%22R%22%22%22ie%5C%27O%3C-1-%7B%3B%7Dd%27Soo&input=TOOOOT)

Answer (score 6):

## PHP, <s>137</s> 135

Requires error reporting off and PHP 5.4+. Input is GET variable `a`.

```
<?=explode(~ß,~­ß¼Üß¼ÔÔßµž‰žß¬œž“žß¾Š‹¶‹ß¾‘“›¼ß«¶Ò½¾¬¶¼ß½Š“š˜Š’ßµž‰žŒœ–‹ß²ž‹—š’ž‹–œžß¾œ‹–‘¬œ–‹)[levenshtein(PHP,$_GET[a])-1];
```

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 3C 3F 3D 65 78 70 6C 6F - 64 65 28 7E DF 2C 7E AD |<?=explode(~ ,~ |
00000010: DF BC DC DF BC D4 D4 DF - B5 9E 89 9E DF AC 9C 9E |                |
00000020: 93 9E DF BE 8A 8B 90 B6 - 8B DF BE 8D 91 90 93 9B |                |
00000030: BC DF AB B6 D2 BD BE AC - B6 BC DF BD 8A 9D 9D 93 |                |
00000040: 9A 98 8A 92 DF B5 9E 89 - 9E 8C 9C 8D 96 8F 8B DF |                |
00000050: B2 9E 8B 97 9A 92 9E 8B - 96 9C 9E DF BE 9C 8B 96 |                |
00000060: 90 91 AC 9C 8D 96 8F 8B - 29 5B 6C 65 76 65 6E 73 |        )[levens|
00000070: 68 74 65 69 6E 28 50 48 - 50 2C 24 5F 47 45 54 5B |htein(PHP,$_GET[|
00000080: 61 5D 29 2D 31 5D 3B    -                         |a])-1];|
00000087;
```

Readable version:

```
<?=explode(' ','R C# C++ Java Scala AutoIt ArnoldC TI-BASIC Bubblegum Javascript Mathematica ActionScript')[levenshtein(PHP,$_GET[a])-1];
```

Answer (score 6):

## C, 183

```
main(s){char* a[12]={"R","C#","C++","Java","COBOL","Python","Clipper","VBScript","Smalltalk","Javascript","Mathematica","ActionScript"};printf(a[strlen(gets(&s))-!!strchr(&s,67)-1]);}
```

Picking a language with a one character name lets you cheat with the distance calculation: any string's distance from "C" is just the length of the string, minus one if it includes "C". I imagine R or J could beat this using the same strategy.

Comment: How come `gets(&s)` doesn't crash?

Comment: I'm not sure, it works on Anarchy Golf and ideone but is clearly not really cricket. I imagine it's using the unused memory allocated for ARGV.

Comment: I'm a bit late, but `a[9];main(s){gets(a);s=strlen(a)-!!strchr(a,67);printf("S%s","\0R\0oT\0taq\0ADOL\0onata\0nowman\0nowball\0nowflake\0tackstack\0hakespeare\0pyrodecimal"+s*~-s/2);}` is 162 bytes and avoids the worst of the compiler-specific behavior. It still requires ASCII, two's complement `~`, and `sizeof(int)>1`.

Answer (score 5):

## Perl 5, <s>325</s> 276

Using a bit of recursion to calculate the Levenshtein distance.

```
@X=(P,e,r,l);$y=@Y=split//,pop;sub L{my($n,$m)=@_;return$m,if!$n;return$n,if!$m;my$c=$X[$n]eq$Y[$m]?0:1;(sort{$a<=>$b}(L($m-1,$n)+1,L($m,$n-1)+1,L($m-1,$n-1)+$c))[0]}print qw(C C# C++ Java COBOL Python Clipper VBScript Smalltalk Javascript Mathematica ActionScript)[L(4,$y)-1]
```

My original version had some issues with the longer inputs.
Till I realised that the Perl sort function sorts alphabetically.

Using substrings instead of arrays turns out to make it slightly longer.

```
@L=qw(C C# C++ Java COBOL Python Clipper VBScript Smalltalk Javascript Mathematica ActionScript);sub l{my($s,$t)=@_;return length($t)if!$s;return length($s)if!$t;my($u,$v)=(substr($s,1),substr($t,1));substr($s,0,1)eq substr($t,0,1)?l($u,$v):(sort{$a<=>$b}(l($u,$v),l($s,$v),l($u,$t)))[0]+1}print$L[l('Perl',pop)-1]
```

#### Test

```
$ perl levenshtein.pl Php
C++
```

Answer (score 3):

## J, 115 bytes

```
{&((}.&'YABC'&.>|.i.4),(g'SMITHb'),'Clojure';(g'ComeFrom2'),((g=:}:;])'StackStacks'),<'CoffeeScript')@<:@(#-'J'&e.)
```

This is using histocrat's calculation trick (using a 1-letter language), and generates the following list of languages:

```
┌─┬──┬───┬────┬─────┬──────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┬──────────┬───────────┬────────────┐
│C│BC│ABC│YABC│SMITH│SMITHb│Clojure│ComeFrom│ComeFrom2│StackStack│StackStacks│CoffeeScript│
└─┴──┴───┴────┴─────┴──────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┴──────────┴───────────┴────────────┘
```

e.g.:

```
   {&((}.&'YABC'&.>|.i.4),(g'SMITHb'),'Clojure';(g'ComeFrom2'),((g=:}:;])'StackStacks'),<'CoffeeScript')@<:@(#-'J'&e.) 'C++'
┌───┐
│ABC│
└───┘
   {&((}.&'YABC'&.>|.i.4),(g'SMITHb'),'Clojure';(g'ComeFrom2'),((g=:}:;])'StackStacks'),<'CoffeeScript')@<:@(#-'J'&e.) 'ActionScript'
┌────────────┐
│CoffeeScript│
└────────────┘
   f=:{&((}.&'YABC'&.>|.i.4),(g'SMITHb'),'Clojure';(g'ComeFrom2'),((g=:}:;])'StackStacks'),<'CoffeeScript')@<:@(#-'J'&e.)
   f 'Jython'
┌─────┐
│SMITH│
└─────┘
   f 'Python'
┌──────┐
│SMITHb│
└──────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 73 bytes

Not even a single-character language name and still the shortest answer here!

```
•äƵí•hR.L<Uõ'R„oT…taq.•₃γ•.•~ÙÚ•„€Ó…Ž„€Óïß…€ÓfŠ°„Â‚Â‚¦'Ïº¦“p¾»oãá“)Xè'Sìá
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOiw0uObT28FsjICNLzsQk9vFU96FHDvPyQRw3LShIL9YASj5qaz20G0iB23eGZh2eBxBrmPWpac3gyUNXRvTDO4fWH5wMFwOy0owsObQBKHG561DALTBxapn64/9CuQ8seNcwpOLTv0O78w4sPLwRyNCMOr1APPrzm8ML//w3NnJyN3AA)

```
•äƵí•hR.L<U...Xè'Sìá  # full program
                   á  # get only letters of...
       .L             # Levenshtein distance between...
                      # implicit input...
       .L             # and...
•äƵí•                 # 14793296...
     h                # in hexadecimal...
      R               # reversed...
         <            # minus 1...
          U   Xè      # th element of...
           ...        # ["", "R", "oT", "taq", "ADOL", "onata", "now man", "now ball", "nowf lake", "tack stack", "hakespeare", "p yro decimal"]
                  ì   # prepended with...
                'S    # literal
```